# Is it a good idea to convert large excel to json for mass upload in database?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to provide my users the capability of bulk upload. These are excel files which we can upload in the website.

Is it a good idea to convert large excel (probably 8000-10000 rows) into json and then pass it to Web API to parse it and then pass the data in the form of xml to database?

Could there be performance issues with this approach? If yes then what would be the better approach?

I am using angular2, typescript and c#. Here is the code:

```
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
        var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
        var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onload = function (event: FileReaderEvent) {
            var result = event.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(result, { type: 'binary' });

            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                console.log(json_object);
            });          
        }
        myReader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    }
```

Comment: I don't get what the question is about. Why would you do the conversion in the browser instead of just uploading it to the server and do the conversion there? If you really want to know the performance impact, then create a benchmark. We don't know your Excel files.

Comment: Excel files would contain 8-10 columns and may contain 5000-6000 rows. I don't know how to receive file format in Web API (searching on that). Just wanted to know the best practice.

Comment: If you send the excel file to the server, then it's just a binary file and the browser and the server don't care what application specific format it actually is. Only the code that converts it from Excel format to XML needs to know.

Comment: Correct. I can read it as binary string at client side but what data type should be used to receive it in API controller?

Comment: "API controller" does mean server? You receive it as binary string (probably base64 encoded) and than convert it back to the pure binary format before you process or store it.